# Can we generate electricity through flying airplanes?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, friction

Frictional electricity makes the charges get separated so when the airplanes are running in air at very high speeds, resistance will be created by the air so due to this frictional electricity will be developed on the surface of the plane, so by this method can we generate electricity?

Comment: Yes, there will be charge separation across the wings, for example, but it is not worth the effort to collect this energy. It is too small compared to the engine of the plane.

Comment: the wings lose charges to air as the wings mostly are made of metal such as aluminum , so I don't think there will be a negative source which would provide electrons back to the plane unless the charges in the plane become significant , this providing electrons back could be the form of current but it may be very negligible as @naturallyInconsistent said

Comment: Hi gethu sudarsan. Welcome to Phys.SE. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-estimate of the frictional electricity as compared to the spent fuel?

Comment: And, as always, there are the laws of thermodynamics: at best you will only get back the energy you put in. Hence it is more efficient to burn the fuel in a turbine to drive an electric generator.